# Are the Font Awesome 3.2 docs still accessible?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-3.2

I am using Font Awesome 3.2. Font Awesome just released version 4.0. Prior to the 4.0 release I would view Font Awesome's documentation at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/. The new version has differing icon names and makes it difficult to work between the old and new documentation.

Are the 3.2 docs still available? Can I download 3.2 docs?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The documentation for 3.2.1 has been archived at:

- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/

There's an article for upgrading from 3.1.2 to 4 on the Github wiki for the Font Awesome project:

- [Upgrading from 3.2.1 to 4](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4)

You can also download earlier releases from the project's [Releases](http://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases) page.  The 3.2.1 release does include docs, but they must be compiled to be useful.

Generally speaking, you can always check the Wayback Machine as a last resort, which has cached versions of some of the docs from previous releases based on date:

- [Cached version of FontAwesome site from 3.2.1 release](http://web.archive.org/web/20130929055652/http://fontawesome.io/)

Comment: Thanks, the cached version would do it. About previous release, i download it but can't figure how to compile it (i mean, which tool compiles it?)

Comment: I believe you need to compile them using Jekyll, a Ruby static site templating engine (http://jekyllrb.com/).  Also, I just found the archived 3.2.1 docs online and updated my answer with the URL. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why FontAwesome decided to make it so difficult to get to the old icons...

Comment: what a pain in the ass. I have this stuff baked in at a low level. I love the set, but this update is painful.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Looks like they're pushing for money with v4.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a set of SED regexp to convert class name of font-awesome 4.0.0 to font-awesome.3.2.1 equivalent.

Look at this :
https://gist.github.com/guli/7154067

To use it :

`sed -f sed_rules.sed < font-awesome.css > font-awesome.css.fixed`

Feel free to comment or fix the gist :)

Comment: I just fixed some issues on the gist.

Comment: Bless your soul! I was about to sit down and do this, but you have saved me!

Comment: sorry, maybe you can provide some tutorial how to use this? :)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a simple Python tool to migrate HTML from font awesome 3.2 to 4.0. It may be of use to you.

You can grab it here: https://github.com/robert-b-clarke/font-awesome-3-to-4

Tested migrating a batch of Django templates from font awesome v3.2.1 to v4.0.3. Patches, fixes and tweaks are of course welcome :)