# Is there an upgrade guide for Font Awesome 3.2.x to Font Awesome 4.0?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-3.2, font-awesome-4

[Font Awesome 4.0](http://fontawesome.io/?4) is a complete rewrite of Font Awesome from the ground up. One of the major new features is that icons are now namespaced. In addition to namespacing the icons utilize a new naming convention based on consistency and predictability. Unfortunately, this new naming convention is a vast departure from Font Awesome 3.2.1.

Is there an upgrade guide from from Font Awesome 3.2.1 to Font Awesome 4.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a fair amount of Googling came across [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569853/61654) which in addition to other documentation questions about Font Awesome 3.2.1 links to a [Font Awesome upgrade guide from 3.2.1 to 4.0.0](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4).

Answer (score 1):

I created a grunt plugin that automates updating from version 3 - 4.

Check it out at https://github.com/jdewit/grunt-html-upgrader