# Where do I get Font Awesome 3 docs?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4, font-awesome-3.2

I am still using Font Awesome 3 in my app and it seems that the docs are now v4 only? And version 4 changed the names of the classes for icons now so I'm not entirely sure which to use? For example, `fa-check-square` in v4 isn't `icon-check-square` in v3 as you'd expect, but `icon-check-sign`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the Font Awesome 3.2 docs still accessible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569213/are-the-font-awesome-3-2-docs-still-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I don't find how to access to information about the previous versions into the official page. In this version It will be a big problem because the class names was changed. I hope that the FontAwesome team solve it soon.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/ answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569853/1203628